# Synapse: Pass lookup value (column name) into a stored proc parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory, lookup, azure-synapse

I have below code where I get full set of file names and for all the file names I need to set the in_progress_flag =1 . Which is done by calling a stored proc.

The Output of Get Valid Entity is like below

```
{
"count": 2,
"value": [
    {
        "Entity_Name": "Member",
        "File_Name": "MemberPARQUET"
    },
    {
        "Entity_Name": "Dealer_Group",
        "File_Name": "Dealer_Group.PARQUET"
    }
]}
```

The Stored Procedure is having parameter, which will take file_name from the lookup to update its status to 1.

Currently I am using like below

```
@activity('Get Valid Entity Names').output.File_Name
```

Which is failing with error `"The expression 'activity('Get Valid Entity Names').output.File_Name' cannot be evaluated because property 'File_Name' doesn't exist, available properties are 'count, value, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, billingReference, durationInQueue'.",`

Any help on how to call a value from Lookup into a parameter please

[image]

Comment: try `@activity('Get Valid Entity Names').output.value[0].File_Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The expression 'activity('Get Valid Entity Names').output.File_Name' cannot be evaluated because property 'File_Name' doesn't exist, available properties are 'count, value, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, billingReference, durationInQueue'."

The error you are getting because lookup output does not contain  `File_Name` attribute directly its under the value array so to access it you need to use expression like below:

```json
@activity('Get Valid Entity Names').output.value[0].File_Name
```

As value is an array above expression will fetch the filename from 0 the index element from value array.

> The Stored Procedure is having parameter, which will take file_name from the lookup to update its status to 1.

If you want to iterate on each filename take Foreach activity and pass the expression for items as

```json
@activity('Get Valid Entity Names').output.value
```

and then under Foreach take your store procedure activity and iterate on each file using `@item().File_Name`

Comment: @activity('Get Valid Entity Names').output.value I used this for the parameter, it took value "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]" in updating the stored proc. 

My idea is to update all the array values in one go with status =1 . Any help please.

@Pratik Lad

Comment: as you have the values are in the array so update that you need to iterate on each item in one go you can't update it.